# large txt file or mysql database to json

Tags: mysql, json, file

I am using elasticsearch to index some  data, the data source is variable, such as txt or sql file.
the first step I think I should do is convert all the data to json formate,such as read txt file or mysql database then write the data to file with json formate, at last import the the data elasticsearch.
but the problem is the file is very large and it will cost long time, one example is the txt file will be 16GB or the mysql database will be 50GB.

if there is some way I can use to read the large txt  file or database quikly?

any idea is apprecitae....

Comment: When you say `it costs a long time`, what's your current approach?

Comment: @JanZeiseweis an 4GB file will cost more than 3 hours..

Comment: What exactly takes 3 hours? Converting a 4GB text file into json format or indexing it with elastic search?
What are you currently using to do the transformation? Python ruby bash perl?

Comment: Converting a 4GB text file into json format cost 3 hours, I am using python.also I index the json file to elasticsearch cost more than 4 hours..